# What is contains in uncashed RAM of linux?

Tags: linux, memory

tell me please, when i execute the free -m command in linux terminal i view
-/+ buffers/cache string, which show memory without caches and buffers... what is contains in memory which without caches and buffers? Binaries of programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory that `free` shows as used is just that, all memory used by your system. This is memory set aside by the kernel for anything from storing the actual code of a running program, to the data used by that program (such as variables). For example, if you are running firefox, the number represents the memory used to store the firefox executable code (in ELF format) as well as all the data firefox needs to run, like the html and images for pages.

Basically all memory requested with (and granted to) `malloc` (and family).

See also:

- [Meaning of the buffers/cache line in the output of free](https://serverfault.com/questions/85470/meaning-of-the-buffers-cache-line-in-the-output-of-free)
- [In Linux, what is the difference between “buffers” and “cache”
  reported by the free command?](https://serverfault.com/questions/23433/in-linux-what-is-the-difference-between-buffers-and-cache-reported-by-the-f)

Comment: Thanks, i'm right understand you, what for example firefox stored him binaries and him data in memory which show in string  -/+ buffers/cache in     column of used?

Comment: I have edited my answer, make sure to +1 and accept the answer if it answers your question.